# Automapper force destination property to null

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a destination object like this which has collections `A` and `D` auto initialized.

```cs
public class DestinationClass
{       
    public SomeObject[] A = new[] { new SomeObject() };
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public SomeObject[] D = new[] { new SomeObject() };
}
```

And source class

```cs
public class SourceClass
{
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set the collection properties `A` and `D` of destination objects as null after mapping as they are not present in the source object. Right now they are initialized with value from inline initialization.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can use the `PostMap` action of automapper. Read here - https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html

Comment: `ForMember(d => d.A, o => o.MapFrom(s => null))`. And the same for `D`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# automapper map not null object to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788814/c-sharp-automapper-map-not-null-object-to-null)