# c# automapper map not null object to null

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like in automapper to always set on of the values of my object to null.

```
 CreateMap<Activity, Activity>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Category, null );
```

however I am receiving a null refrence exception

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=AutoMapper
  StackTrace:
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpression`2.ForDestinationMember[TMember](MemberInfo destinationProperty, Action`1 memberOptions)
   at Application.Core.MappingProfiles..ctor() in C:\Users\Bryan.Dellinger.Apps\Documents\code\EEMRewrite\Application\Core\MappingProfiles.cs:line 17
```

here is  my activity class

```
  public class Activity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start {get; set;}
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string Description {get; set;}

        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: `.ForMember(x => x.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom<Category>(_ => null);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoMapper settings properties to null on destination object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125997/automapper-settings-properties-to-null-on-destination-object)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048198/automapper-force-destination-property-to-null (although it does not have an accepted answer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125997/automapper-settings-properties-to-null-on-destination-object is not a duplicate of this question. In that question it is asked how to make destination properties not get replaced by the source properties and keep their original value instead. This is a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Johnathan Barclay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8126362/johnathan-barclay) gave the correct answer in the comments which is to use:

```cs
CreateMap<Activity, Activity>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom<Category>(_ => null);
```